# telethon fetch access_hass by user_id

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I am trying to send a message to a user that does not have username and not in my contact list (using [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) ), but I don't know the access_hash, only the user_id.

1- Is it possible to do that?

2- How do I fetch the access_hash for a user?

Answer (score 6):

No library can figure out the `access_hash` from only the user, chat or channel ID. However, if the library has "seen" this user before (through `.get_dialogs()`, or through an `Update`, or in any other way).

Telethon will by default save the received information into the `*.session` file. To make use of it, call `client.get_input_entity(user_id)`, and it will return a `InputPeerUser` if possible (i.e. the library saw such user). This function also accepts usernames and phone numbers, in case those are more convenient, and don't forget to check the [official documentation](http://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/basic/entities.html).